# Is it possible to discover where a vinyl record was physically pressed?

Tags: vinyl, vinyl-pressing

Do you know if it is possible, from the cover/back-cover or from the vinyl itself, to understand where a vinyl has been pressed?

I know on the vinyl are engraved the serial number/barcode, but I don't know anything about the indication of the plant or the country where the vinyl has been pressed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Record stamper Matrix codes can be used to identify the pressing plant, but the correlating lists may not be publicly available, or may have only been compiled by collectors, rather than the plants themselves.

The first part of the number will match the information on the record sleeve & will be the same for all copies.
Marks following that can vary - stamper or cut number, if multiple stampers &/or cuts were made. Again finding accurate information on this is going to be difficult.

Then there are always the famous "Porky Prime Cut"-type additions made by cutting engineers over the years; which can serve to change the value of a particular pressing, but give no real information as to the plant used.

There is some information on Wikipedia - [Matrix number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_number) but many of the referenced links are no longer available.

http://vinyls.altervista.org/Vinyl/vin_emicc.htm contains a list of EMI country codes.